# Python - Alphabets, numbers and combinations

Tags: python, numeric, alphabetical

I have a list with alphabets and numbers in python, all of which are IDs for assets with data.
I need to achieve the following:

1. Separate the alphabets and numbers in two separate lists.
2. Use the lists to get the data from two separate SQL databases.
3. Put back the alphabet and number IDs IN THE SAME ODER along with the data I got for both.

I know the second point is not precise, I can do that: the first and last are causing the real difficulty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is the list I have:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2]
I would like to get this split into the following lists
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2]
['VWO', 'IWF','VEA']
The I will get dataframe with the data associated with both sets of lists, something like:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2
x,x,x,x,x,x,y,y,y]

['VWO', 'IWF','VEA']

Comment: Here is the list I have:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2]

I would like to get this split into the following lists
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2]
['VWO', 'IWF','VEA']

The I will get dataframe with the data associated with both sets of lists, something like:

[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2
x,x,x,x,x,x,y,y,y]

['VWO', 'IWF','VEA'
z,z,z]

Then I would like this to be put as a dataframe with the same order of columns with the data associated with it:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2
x,x,x,x,x,x,y,y,y,z,z,x]

Comment: @user36899 your question and additional comments are not clear. Please update your question to show the input and output you want. So someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can clone the original list first, then do whatever you need to do with the clone list. After you get the data, use the original list for ordering to join the two lists together

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to want to run a query for each value in a list, using one query if the current value is a number and another query if the current value is a string.

You can do this by iterating over your inputs, running the appropriate query on each value and keeping a list of the results.

Supposing you have the functions `queryNumber` and `queryString`, which each interact with your database, here is an example of how you can solve this problem:

```
data = [82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2]
results = []

for x in data:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        result = queryString(x)
    elif isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float):
        result = queryNumber(x)
    results.append(result)

full_results = data + results
```

Sample `full_results`:

```
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2, 'result for 82', 'result for 6', 'result for 6', 'result for 2', 'result for 7', 'result for 1', 'result for 149', 'result for 139', 'result for 3', "result for 'VWO'", "result for 'IWF'", "result for 'VEA'", 'result for 2']
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was unable to post complete response. Please see below:

Here is the list I have:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2]

Get this split into the following lists
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2]
['VWO', 'IWF','VEA']

The I will get dataframe with the data associated with both sets of lists, something like:

[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 2
x,x,x,x,x,x,y,y,y]
['VWO', 'IWF','VEA'
z,z,z]
Then put in dataframe in same order of columns with the data in it:
[82, 6, 6, 2, 7, 1, 149, 139, 3, 'VWO', 'IWF', 'VEA', 2
x,x,x,x,x,x,y,y,y,z,z,x]

Comment: I would like to point out, this has to be written in a general form since the code is handling input form a user

Comment: @user36899 does this edit help with the problem? if not please let me know what I can adjust